# CSS Border Radius doesn't work in Safari after switching to gatsby-plugin-image

Tags: css, gatsby

CSS Border Radius doesn't work in Safari after switching to gatsby-plugin-image

on my laptop I can see the border radius of the image, but it doesn't seem to work on iphone or iPad.
(i.e. the image is square only on iPhone / iPad, I didn't see border-radius:25px being applied to the image)

EDIT 11-24: sorry this is the code snippet I'm using styled-component

```
export const MyImageContainer = styled(GatsbyImage)`
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
`
```

Comment: Can you share your implementation details? (CSS, SCSS, styled-components, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar issue with border radius after migrating to gatsby-plugin-image.

Not sure if this addresses your question, you might want to add more details and some code snippets will be helpful.

I'm using styled-component for my project. My solution was to target the img

For example

```
export const MyImageVariable = styled(GatsbyImage)`
 border-radius: 50%;
  img {
    border-radius:50%;
   }
`
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is an old 'bug'. This css hack should fix it.

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```